# Replace All Values In Table Column

Tags: xslt, replace, html-table, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to add a value (in this case the string "I Added This") to all -nodes within a specific column if the column does contain a certain value (in this case the text "I Want You") using XSLT 2.0.

This means, if I have the following table:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>header value</th>
            <th>I Want You</th>
            <th>header value</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>value 4</td>
            <td>value 5</td>
            <td>value 6</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

the output should be this after I apply the xslt script:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>header value</th>
            <th>I Want You</th>
            <th>header value</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>I Added This value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>value 4</td>
            <td>I Added This value 5</td>
            <td>value 6</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

To achieve that I wrote many different stylesheets but I didn't even came close:

Copying the entire table:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This gets me the values of the column I want to change - but from there I don't know how to prepend each td-value with the phrase "I Added This Value"

```
<xsl:template match="//th[contains(lower-case(.), 'I Want You')]">

    <xsl:variable name="tdPos" select="count(preceding-sibling::td)+2"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="current()/parent::*/following-sibling::tr">
        <xsl:value-of select="./td[$tdPos]/text()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Any hints that might point me into the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Will the text for which you are searching ("I want you", in this case), only ever appear in the first header row, or can it occur in any row on the table?

Comment: Good question. It can apear in any row. But only the rows below the row with the value "I want you" should be changed. Anything above should stay unchanged.

Comment: Please see my answer. Could you please accept the best answers. Click on the check mark next to the answer that you want to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem worth noting is that your "contains" test is not quite right

```
<xsl:template match="//th[contains(lower-case(.), 'I Want You')]">
```

It probably be the following

```
<xsl:template match="//th[contains(lower-case(.), lower-case('I Want You'))]">
```

However, it might be better all round if you parameterise your search values, although you wouldn't be able to use such parameter in the template match. Instead you would just match any cell....

```
<xsl:template match="tr/*">
```

Then you could test if equivalent column on a preceding row has the value you want

```
<xsl:if 
   test="../preceding-sibling::tr/*[$position][contains(., $match)]">
```

(lower-case() command removed for brevity)

Here $position will be a variable containing the current cell position, and $match is the variable you are looking for.

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="match" select="'I Want You'" />
   <xsl:param name="add" select="'I Added This'" />

   <xsl:template match="tr/*">
      <xsl:variable name="position" select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>          <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <xsl:if test="../preceding-sibling::tr/*[$position][contains(lower-case(.), lower-case($match))]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($add, ' ')" />
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is produced

```
<table>
<tr>
   <th>header value</th>
   <th>I Want You</th>
   <th>header value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>value 1</td>
   <td>I Added This value 2</td>
   <td>value 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>value 4</td>
   <td>I Added This value 5</td>
   <td>value 6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And when applied to this XML

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>header value</th>
      <th>header value</th>
      <th>header value</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>I Want You</td>
      <td>value 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>value 3</td>
      <td>value 4</td>
      <td>value 5</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The following is output

```
<table>
<tr>
   <th>header value</th>
   <th>header value</th>
   <th>header value</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>value 1</td>
   <td>I Want You</td>
   <td>value 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>value 3</td>
   <td>I Added This value 4</td>
   <td>value 5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've fixed it to set the correct use of positioning now. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - interestingly enough, I did not downvote this answer. Your pettiness and your willingness to complain about it is alarming. In fact, I upvoted this because, unlike your answer, it addresses the more comprehensive solution.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right lines - you just needed to do a condition as you output nodes so that, in the case of TD nodes, check if the cousin TH node at the same index featured the required text.

```
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:variable name='curr_pos' select='position()' />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select='@*' />
        <xsl:if test='name() = "td" and /table/tr[1]/th[$curr_pos] = "I Want You"'>prefix - </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select='text()' />
        <xsl:apply-templates select='*' />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You can run it at [this playground session](http://www.xmlplayground.com/uo6iNO).

Comment: This is wrong for multi-table documents. Cute and short though.

Comment: ...criticism, which is fair enough, but no insightful correction? :) I initially tried `[position(current())]` in the predicate, but no dice, hence I went with the var. p.s. the question wasn't multi-table.

Comment: Ok, Explanations and correction: position() is wrong because it counts the white space between <td> and the next <td> as a text node. Potentially you could have no white space in the header row, but white space and even comments between the data rows. Solution? Use count(preceding-sibling::td) instead. Now for the multi table bit. The solution is just to make the navigation path from the data <td> to the header <th> relative instead of absolute. The expression ../../tr[1]/th hits the mark.

Comment: Doesn't `*|@*` avoid white space nodes? I'm aware of the problem you describe with the `node()|@*` selector - i.e., as you say, white space is also selected and treated as countable where `position()` is concerned. http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N6099.html#d8492e362

Comment: Yes and no. * means element child, so yes that does not include white space, BUT postion() is not coming from the match clause. It comes from the outer context, which is not explicit to the template. Even if whitespace was not a problem (but it still is), you have the additional problem of non-table elements. Remember this is html, so one must assume that there can be all kinds of formatting and other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

**Probably the shortest and simplest possible transformation (no `preceding-sibling::`, no `position()`, no conditional instructions, no variables)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tr/*[2]/text()[not(. = 'I Want You')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('I Added This ', .)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>header value</th>
        <th>I Want You</th>
        <th>header value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>value 1</td>
        <td>value 2</td>
        <td>value 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>value 4</td>
        <td>value 5</td>
        <td>value 6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>header value</th>
      <th>I Want You</th>
      <th>header value</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>I Added This value 2</td>
      <td>value 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>value 4</td>
      <td>I Added This value 5</td>
      <td>value 6</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies every matched node "as-is".
2. There is a single overriding template. It matches any text node whose string value isn't the string `'I Want You'` *and* that is a child of any element (so both `th` and `td` are matched) that is the second element child of a `tr`. This template outputs the concatenation of the string `'I Added This '` and the string value of the current (matched) node.

**Do note**: This is an XSLT 1.0 solution but it works the same with an XSLT 2.0 processor with no changes at all. It is safe (if nessecary) to change the `version` attribute of `xsl:stylesheet` to "2.0".

Comment: I don't believe this solution is comprehensive. It works in the specific case that the OP provided, but if a reasonable change is made -- for instance, if "I Want You" appears in the first `<th>`, rather than the second -- the desired result is *not* produced.

Comment: @ABach: The OP `hasn't` asked for a more generic solution. His sample XML is just this -- a *sample* XML. This means that he wants to get just the *idea* how this can be done and he would then implement this idea in his own code. My experience has shown that quite frequently giving the user generalized solutions makes it difficult for them to immediately see and understand the main idea. Often the user simply doesn't need and doesn't use such generalizations. Your downvote only speaks about you and doesn't decrease the value of this answer.

Comment: Wow - not sure why you're so defensive. You usually appreciate more comprehensive solutions; I figured that in this case, you'd feel the same way. Apparently, I was mistaken.

Comment: Additionally, please refrain from deleting comments that you believe no longer serve your purpose (as you did with your abrasive comment on @Tim C's answer approximately 13 minutes ago).

Comment: @ABach: To be fair, that might not have been Dimitre's doing, a lot of Dimitre's comments are moderated away.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim C! It's working like a charm and it's a really nice solution on top of that! Although I'm having a little problem if there are multiple tables in the document I apply this stylesheet on. It also adds the value in tables that do not contain the "I Want You" value. Any workaround for that? I tried selecting all the tables and then run through its columns seperatly but this results into no output.

```
<xsl:template match="//table">
  <xsl:for-each select="/tr/*">
    <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:if test="../preceding-sibling::tr/*[position() = $position][contains(lower-case(.), lower-case($match))]">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($add, ' ')" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: see my answer. It solves your multiple table problem. Also Tim's solution is not completely correct. Please accept one of the answers with a tick.

Comment: I did try my (amended) solution on a multiple table problem, and it looks OK to me! Perhaps amending your original question to show multiple tables would help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This style-sheet (also works with XSLT 1.0) ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="td">
  <xsl:variable name="col" select="count(preceding-sibling::td)+1" /> 
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <xsl:if test="contains(../../tr[1]/th[$col], 'I Want You')">
     <xsl:value-of select="'I Added This '" /> 
   </xsl:if>  
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... when applied to your sample input, will produce your required output.

Tim's answer is incorrect or at least not consistently correct. The position() function is tricky. The problem is that position() includes white-space nodes and other non-table stuff that you might have in a html table such as microdata formats. If the white-spacing in the header row is different to the data row, Tim C's solution will not work. The count() is required.

I deliberately left the lower-case() bit out. I leave trivial details of the test to the OP.

Also here is an even simpler XSLT 2.0 solution ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="td[
     for $col in position() return
       contains(../../tr[1]/th[$col], 'I Want You')]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="'I Added This '" /> 
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description of the position() function! The count() fucntion is most likely a more fitting function.

Comment: Thanks. Although you should give credit where credit is due. If you scan all the solutions, Dimitre's solution is the simplest and smallest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short, correct answer that handles "I Want This" in any `<th>` and works in documents with numerous such tables (should they be semantically correct).

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Template #1 - Identity Template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Template #2 -->
  <xsl:template match="tr[position() &gt; 1]/td[position() = count(../../th[. = 'I Want You']/preceding-sibling::th) + 1]/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('I Added This ', .)" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**is applied to this XML document:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header value</th>
    <th>I Want You</th>
    <th>header value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value 1</td>
    <td>value 2</td>
    <td>value 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value 4</td>
    <td>value 5</td>
    <td>value 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**the wanted result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>header value</th>
    <th>I Want You</th>
    <th>header value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value 1</td>
    <td>I Added This value 2</td>
    <td>value 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value 4</td>
    <td>I Added This value 5</td>
    <td>value 6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that if you have multiple such `<table>` elements in your document, this XSLT covers that case, as well. This isn't something you specifically asked for, but it's not outside the realm of possibility, so I figured I'd cover it.

**XML:**

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>header value</th>
      <th>I Want You</th>
      <th>header value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>value 2</td>
      <td>value 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value 4</td>
      <td>value 5</td>
      <td>value 6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>I Want You</th>
      <th>header value</th>
      <th>header value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>value 2</td>
      <td>value 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value 4</td>
      <td>value 5</td>
      <td>value 6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

**RESULT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>header value</th>
      <th>I Want You</th>
      <th>header value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>I Added This value 2</td>
      <td>value 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value 4</td>
      <td>I Added This value 5</td>
      <td>value 6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>I Want You</th>
      <th>header value</th>
      <th>header value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I Added This value 1</td>
      <td>value 2</td>
      <td>value 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>I Added This value 4</td>
      <td>value 5</td>
      <td>value 6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

**Explanation:**

1. **Template #1 - The Identity Template** - copies everything as-is. We overwrite this template in subsequent templates.
2. **Template #2** - this template matches a doozy of an XPath: get all text contained within `<td>` elements whose position matches the `<th>` element (within the nearest "header" `<tr>`) with a value of "I Want You". For this text, return a new value that is the concatenation of "I Added This" and the original text.

Comment: Thanks, ABach, this is working perfectly.

I have to thank all contributers to my question once again! You guys are great! Your answers also helped me alot more to understand xslt.